Did UK NHS nurses mistreat a Jewish boy because they "supported Palestine"?
Claim: A 9 year old boy with blood disorder was mistreated at the Royal Manchester Children's Hospital (the way I interpreted the claim was that he was actually denied treatment and made to lie on the floor instead of hospital bed, but it was a guy reading out some article which wasn't linked so not sure) by nurses wearing "free Palestine" badges; because he was dressed in Jewish garb.
Notability of the claim: video has 100K+ views, 12K+ upvotes; not sure the notability of whatever it was citing.

The notes with the video are contradictory. One paragraph says "The nurses were all wearing Free Palestine pins" and the next says "the same couple of nurses." Apparently the evidence is supported by an uncle who wasn't present, and not even in UK.

TBH I didn't catch the 'Jewish garb' bit in the video, but the author does state several times that the boy was Jewish. There's a couple of photos around one minute in https://youtu.be/en2Gj_JesTU?t=58 and I don't see any "Jewish garb", but maybe it was removed by then.

https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news/childrens-hospital-issues-statement-after-28874025

https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2024/03/21/nhs-trust-pro-palestine-nurses-jewish-boy-poor-treatment/  says the uncle is based in Israel. Both articles say an investigation was launched.

Also worth noting that patients lying on the floor isn't exactly unheard of in the UK: Kent, more Kent, Yorkshire, Liverpool...

@StuartF  - NOT what everyone whining how awful US healthcare is and how we need to do UK style tells us :)
